# What steps do I need to take before I can malloc some other amount of memory in the SAME variable name I have used in a loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc

In a loop, I malloc a certain amount of memory, use it to store some string.

When the loop occurs, I will have to malloc another amount of memory, to the same
variable I have used. The amount of memory depends on user's input. Code goes like
following, (I have simplified it)

```
int thisMany;
char *message = NULL;
while (1)
{
    printf("How many characters will you type?");
    scanf("%d\n", thisMany);

    message = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(thisMany+1));
    message[thisMany+1] = '\0';

    for (;thisMany > 0; thismany--) 
    {
        message[thisMany] = a;
    }
    printf("%s", message);

    /* this is the stage where I don't know what to do with 'message' 
    in order for the code to work after the loop */
}
```

I have tried using 'free(message)' and some other stuff. Please let me know if you know something that would make this work.

Comment: `message[thisMany+1] = '\0';` is undefined behavior because it writes past the end of the allocated array. Apart from that, you have to `free(message);` before re-assigning the pointer in order to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: Also, it should be `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char *)` (just think about it), but for **exactly this reason,** you shan't be hard-coding the type. `sizeof message[0]` is the safest way to write this.

Comment: You should also check if your memory allocation succeeds by checking the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Also, it should be `scanf("%d", &thisMany);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (1)
{
    printf("How many characters will you type?");
    scanf("%d\n", thisMany);
```

Your allocation here is not correct: you want to allocate a char pointer, of a given number of characters. So it should be:

```
    message = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(thisMany+1));

    // Always verify *allocs. They're mischievous at best, and often evil.
    if (NULL == message) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
         exit(-1);
    }
```

There was no harm done, however, since sizeof(char *) is four or eight times *larger* than sizeof(char), so you were allocating more memory than necessary. But now this line of code becomes dangerous:

```
    message[thisMany+1] = '\0';
```

You have allocated thisMany+1 characters, numbered from 0 to thisMany. So the thisMany+1-th character falls outside allocated memory; what is called an "off-by-one" buffer overflow. It should be:

```
    // One less than the number given to malloc()
    message[thisMany] = '\0';
```

Finally:

```
    /* this is the stage where I don't know what to do with 'message' 
    in order for the code to work after the loop */
```

What you need to do is to *free* the memory you allocated.

```
    free(message); message = NULL;
```

The reassignment of message to NULL is not strictly necessary but I find it very useful; after being freed, `message` still points to an area of allocated memory, which still has the same content. So you could do

```
    free(message);
    printf("%s\n", message);
```

and *sometimes, maybe often*, it would actually work, hiding a potentially disastrous bug.

Setting message to NULL guarantees this will not happen, and improves the chances that any improper usage will be conspicuous enough to be caught at once. And it makes behaviour deterministic in this respect, which is much better for catching bugs.

An alternative, as already pointed out, is to set message to NULL before the loop, and then use `realloc` instead of `malloc`. `realloc()` will behave just like `malloc` when passed a NULL argument:

```
message = NULL;
for (;;) {
     // Loop
     message = realloc(...);
     if (NULL == message) {
         ...
     }
}
// finally free message outside the loop.
// Checking that it is *not* NULL, in case the check above did not exit
// but just, say, printed an error message and exited the loop via break
if (message != NULL) {
    free(message); message = NULL;
}
```

Comment: "Setting message to NULL guarantees that any improper usage will be caught immediately" - no. Dereferencing `NULL` is just the same undefined behavior than dereferencing any other invalid pointer. (Granted, in practice, it's easier to debug a NULL dereference, but nothing is guaranteed at all.)

Comment: Yes, there are case where setting `message` to NULL is not enough to wreak blatant havoc - `printf()` being a case in point: it would just print "(null)". Indeed, I usually use pointers in more dangerous situations :-) -- but thanks, I'll correct.

Comment: @iserni Thanks. (Incidentally, that `printf()` behavior is just the library writers being smart, cautious and kind; this function doesn't have to check for `NULL`. Too bad a lot of programmers rely on most modern C libraries doing so...)

Comment: @H2CO3, I'm puzzled by your saying in another comment that '`realloc()` returning `NULL`' is fundamentally different from `malloc()` returning `NULL`. Apart from the original buffer becoming unreachable and leaking, is there some other issue lurking?

Comment: @iserni No, it's exactly the original buffer being leaked. That isn't the case when a `malloc()` fails (unless you re-assign to the same pointer, of course). -- Side note: IMO the `ptr = realloc(ptr)` idiom is acceptable when you consider allocation failures fatal errors and `exit()` or `abort()` immediately (I'm doing that in a library I'm working on, because there's no way of recovering from such a failure), but unfortunately, there are a lot of programmers who do it in other situations as well.

Answer (score 0):

After you have finished with the `message` (after `printf`), you should `free (message)` to free it up.

Alternatively you can `realloc` it rather than `malloc`-ing it.